# RubyMine lists too few gems on Vagrant machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, vagrant, rubymine-7

I decided to use remote Ruby SDK in RubyMine 7.1.4.

The Vagrant machine (`hashicorp/precise32`) is set up, RVM, Ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769), Rails 4.2.4 and other required gems are installed and my application runs when started by `rails server` command.

Remote Ruby interpreter has been configured in a following way:

`Settings` > `Languages & Frameworks` > `Ruby SDK and gems` > `Add` > `New remote...`

- Type: Vagrant
- Ruby interpreter path: `/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby` (an output of `which ruby` command)

There are too few gems listed in RubyMine for this remote interpreter:

```
bundler (1.8.4)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
executable-hooks (1.3.2)
gem-wrappers (1.2.7)
minitest (5.4.3)
power_assert (0.2.2)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
test-unit (3.0.8)
```

An actual list printed by `gem list` in SSH console:

```
actionmailer (4.2.4)
actionpack (4.2.4)
actionview (4.2.4)
activeadmin (1.0.0.pre2)
activejob (4.2.4)
activemodel (4.2.4)
activerecord (4.2.4)
activesupport (4.2.4)
arbre (1.0.3)
arel (6.0.3)
awesome_nested_set (3.0.2)
bcrypt (3.1.10)
bigdecimal (1.2.7, 1.2.6)
binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
bourbon (4.2.6)
builder (3.2.2)
bundler (1.10.6, 1.8.4)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
byebug (6.0.2)
coffee-rails (4.1.0)
coffee-script (2.4.1)
coffee-script-source (1.9.1.1)
debug_inspector (0.0.2)
devise (3.5.2)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (2.6.0)
executable-hooks (1.3.2)
formtastic (3.1.3)
formtastic_i18n (0.4.1)
gem-wrappers (1.2.7)
globalid (0.3.6)
has_scope (0.6.0)
i18n (0.7.0)
inherited_resources (1.6.0)
io-console (0.4.3)
jbuilder (2.3.2)
jquery-rails (4.0.5)
jquery-ui-rails (5.0.5)
json (1.8.3, 1.8.1)
kaminari (0.16.3)
loofah (2.0.3)
mail (2.6.3)
mime-types (2.6.2)
mini_portile (0.6.2)
minitest (5.8.2, 5.4.3)
multi_json (1.11.2)
nokogiri (1.6.6.2)
orm_adapter (0.5.0)
polyamorous (1.2.0)
power_assert (0.2.5, 0.2.2)
psych (2.0.15, 2.0.8)
rack (1.6.4)
rack-test (0.6.3)
rails (4.2.4)
rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
rails-dom-testing (1.0.7)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.2)
railties (4.2.4)
rake (10.4.2)
ransack (1.7.0)
rdoc (4.2.0)
responders (2.1.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
rubygems-update (2.4.8)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
sass (3.4.19)
sass-rails (5.0.4)
sdoc (0.4.1)
spring (1.4.0)
sprockets (3.4.0)
sprockets-rails (2.3.3)
sqlite3 (1.3.11)
test-unit (3.1.5, 3.0.8)
thor (0.19.1)
thread_safe (0.3.5)
tilt (2.0.1)
turbolinks (2.5.3)
tzinfo (1.2.2)
uglifier (2.7.2)
warden (1.2.3)
web-console (2.2.1)
```

When I attempt to run the application in RubyMine it outputs an error: `No Rails found in SDK`.

How to configure an interpreter properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the [JetBrains RubyMine Confluence](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/RUBYDEV/Configuring+Remote+Interpreters+via+Vagrant):

> When adding an rvm-based remote interpreter, it is important to specify the gem set in the Ruby interpreter path:

```
<rvm root>/gems/<gem set>
```

Have you tried updating your interpreter path to reflect this requirement?

**Update from the question author:**

The point is to specify the path to gem set **instead of** ruby interpreter path. In my case it was: `/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5` while the path to the interpreter was: `/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby`.

Comment: Yes, everything is clear, but I am surprised that the system did not increase your rep by 50 points.

Comment: Did your reputation increase, because of the edit? I'm not really sure how bounties work.

Comment: I lost 50 points when I started a bounty, then the rep increased by 2 points when I accepted your answer. You should get these 50 points.

Comment: So... I should have to click `+50` icon to award the bounty.

Comment: Does the same still apply to the latest RubyMine (2019.1.2)? I've tried adding the path to the gem set but got "Interpreter doesn't exist on remote server" message in return.

Comment: Apparently the way to do it is to specify path to rvm bin: `/home/vagrant/.rvm/bin/rvm` (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/configuring-remote-interpreters-using-vagrant.html)